# asp.net submenu not popups when I hover on menuitem

Tags: asp.net, menuitem, submenu

I have experienced such problem in asp.net. (visual  studio 2008) net 3.5
I've created menu

```
 <div>
    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" 
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    BackColor="#F7F6F3" 
    DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" 
    Font-Names="Verdana" 
    Font-Size="0.8em" 
    ForeColor="#7C6F57"
    StaticSubMenuIndent="10px">

         <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Item 1">
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Sub Menu 1"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Sub Menu 2"></asp:MenuItem>
            </asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Item 2">
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Sub Menu 1"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Sub Menu 2"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Sub Menu 3">
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Sub Sub Menu 1"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Sub Sub Menu 2"></asp:MenuItem>
                </asp:MenuItem>
            </asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Item 3"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Item 4"></asp:MenuItem>
        </Items>

       <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" ForeColor="White" />
        <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
        <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" />
        <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" />


        <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" ForeColor="White" />
        <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
        <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" />
    </asp:Menu>
```

When I run web page, menu appears, but when I hover on parent menuitem, submenues not popups.  Instead when I click on menuitem the only submenu level is shown and "one level up" link is displayd. How to achieve, popup of submenues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior of the ASP.NET menu control is to display the sub menu items on hover.If this is not happening it means that you have some sort of javascript or css on your page which is over riding the default bahavior.

What I suggest is to create a blank .aspx page and add your menu mark up to this page.Don't add **ANY** javascript or css files to this page, run the new page in the browser and you will see that it works.Now slowly start adding the javascript files and css style rules to the page until the menu sub item displaying stops working.Hopefully this will help you identify the problem.

Comment: Thanks. after I will submit my answer

Comment: I have figure out that, when i upload it to server, all works perfectly. Seems  something's wrong with my machine.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?Did it help you?

Comment: I have uploaded it without any changes made. It means that script is right, I think something is wrong with my browser settings or localhost configuration.